# Is salt bad for kidneys?

Tags: salt, kidney, kidney-stones

I heard from the street that salt is bad for kidneys. But I heard from others that all salt does is pick up blood pressure, which can cause damage to the kidneys.

My question is if salt is bad for someone with low blood pressure but has kidney stones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having kidney stones alone entails [a recommendation for low-sodium diet](https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/5-steps-for-preventing-kidney-stones-201310046721):

> Reduce sodium: A high-sodium diet can trigger kidney stones because it increases the amount of calcium in your urine. So a low-sodium diet is recommended for the stone prone. Current guidelines suggest limiting total daily sodium intake to 2,300 mg. If sodium has contributed to kidney stones in the past, try to reduce your daily intake to 1,500 mg. This will also be good for your blood pressure and heart.